# Права администратора суперпользователя java

Tags: java, permissions

Добрый день. У меня есть программа, в корневой папке которой лежит файл. В случае, если это файл отсутствует в папках, заданных в java.path, мне нужно скопировать его туда и после завершения продолжить выполнение программы. Файл является библиотекой, а папка path имеет ограничение на запись. Как запросить у системы права суперпользователя или получить их, введя пароль во всплывающем окне? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Это понятно, что java кроссплатформенная, и все в это свято верят, но разочарую Вас - это не правда. И множество задач решается в зависимости от операционной системы. Без указания оси эту задачу очень сложно решить.

Comment: Windows 7, Debian, Linux mint. Пока что попался пакет только для FreeBSD.

Comment: Вы нашли решение? Если да то пожалуйста ответьте на свой вопрос.